# How to automatically enable a mode for only one specfic type of buffer?

Tags: dired, hooks, hl-line-mode

I user `dired` to browse file, and I would like to use `hl-line-mode` which highlights the currents line, but I only want it to be enabled automatically when using `dired`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what hooks are for:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I'll search more about hooks.

Answer (score -3):

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'global-hl-line-mode)

Comment: Welcome to Emacs SE!  Unfortunately, this will turn on `hl-mode` globally as soon as the user enters a `dired` buffer for the first time.